# How to edit city name in Geocode JSON response

Tags: here-api

I am getting an incorrect name of my city in reverse geocode JSON response.
Also, there are few other mistakes in name around my city.

1)Correct City Name - Prayagraj, UP, India
In some responses(not at all response) - Prayagaraj
2)Real Location - Naini Prayagraj
    IN RESPONSE - Naini Karchchana

Please tell me the process how to edit the city name and correct other things.

Answer (score 0):

### Reporting an error on Here Maps

Using [wego.here.com](https://wego.here.com/search/Prayagaraj?map=25.4361,81.84718,13,normal) you can:

1. Visit the location you want to report
2. Click feedback (bottom right)
3. Select "Report a Map Error"
4. Fill out your Map Error Report

Comment: Since you're consuming the api. You *could* always edit the results after you retrieve them and display the correct name on your app